# Parsing Float to Int when finding coordinates

Tags: python, parsing, coordinates, jython

I am trying to create a picture with a black circle in the centre.

```
def Circle():
  pic=makeEmptyPicture(200,200)
  centre=(100,100)

  for y in range (0,200):
    for x in range (0,200):
      value =int[( 200/(100-y^2)^.5)]
      if  value!= 0 and x <=value:
        px=getPixel(pic,x,y)
        setColor(px, makeColor(0,0,0))

  return(pic)
```

I am getting  `The error was: 'int' and 'float'`

I can't figure out how to parse value to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value =int[( 200/(100-y^2)^.5)]
```

Use parentheses instead of square brackets—like a function call. Also `^` (bitwise XOR) should be `**` (exponent).

```
value = int(200 / (100 - y**2) ** 0.5)
```

Comment: You're probably getting the second error in your inner loop when y==10, (100-y**2) == 0.

Answer (score 1):

My logic in my code was flawed:

```
def Circle():
  pic=makeEmptyPicture(200,200)
  r=20
  centre=(100,100)

  for y in range (0,200):
    for x in range (0,200):
      px=getPixel(pic,x,y)
      if (( pow((x-100),2)+pow((y-100),2))<pow(r,2)):

        setColor(px, makeColor(0,0,0))

  return(pic)
```

[image: circle]

---

I am retaining the current answer, as the answer, as it dealt with my question, I felt obliged to post an alternate solution to my problem.